# mysql - select order_id from tbl where orders_status_id has never x

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using old mysql version with php version 4 on my website.

My table structure :

```
| orders_status_history_id |  orders_id |  orders_status_id |
|            1             |       22   |         3         |
|            2             |       23   |         2         |
|            3             |       24   |         5         |
|            4             |       23   |         8         |
|            5             |       25   |         5         |
|            6             |       30   |         1         |
|            7             |       26   |         2         |
|            8             |       22   |         4         |
|            10            |       22   |         5         |
|            15            |       48   |         6         |
|            16            |       52   |         8         |
|            17            |       32   |         9         |
|            18            |       50   |         5         |
|            19            |       24   |         5         |
|            22            |       20   |         8         |
|            23            |       1001 |         1         |
|            ..            |       ..   |         ..        |
|            ..            |       ..   |         ..        |
```

My table has 200000+ rows and `orders_status_history_id` is `auto increment`

So my  question is this :

How do i get `orders_status_history_id` where `orders_status_id` has never had  id 5 of `orders_id` ?

For examaple : 
 if `orders_id` 22  had ever `orders_status_id 5` then skip `orders_id` 22 and `orders_id` 23 had never `orders_status_id` 5 then show me this `orders_id` 23

So i expect like this :

```
| orders_status_history_id |  orders_id | 
|            3             |       24   | 
|            4             |       23   | 
|            17            |       32   |
```

**Because these `orders_id` has never had `orders_status_id` id equal to 5. `orders_status_history_id = 3` has never had `orders_id`  = 5**

I hope you understand. Its little bit difficult to explain you for me.

I have try to do something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT orders_status_history_id, orders_id, orders_status_id FROM orders_status_history_tbl where orders_status_id not 5";
```

but it returns all array of where `orders_status_id` is not equal to 5.

Ty for helping

For any further information please ask me.

Comment: **where orders_id has never had orders_status_id 5** this is bit confusing

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: `$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders_status_history_tbl WHERE NOT orders_status_id = '5' ";`  try this.

Comment: @JeesKDenny it returns me array of all data where `orders_status_id` is not equal to 5 but i want `orders_id`  has never had `orders_status_id = '5'`.  I have rewrite a question.

Comment: But in your output `orders_status_history_id` 3 has `orders_status_id` 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT 
     orders_status_history_id,order_id
FROM 
    orders_status_history_tbl 
Where orders_id NOT IN 
  (
      Select Distinct
          orders_id 
      From 
          orders_status_history_tbl 
      Where 
          orders_status_id = 5
  )
```

Comment: no it does not work it shows me `orders_id` 24 even it has `orders_status_id = '5'`  with different  `orders_status_history_id`

Comment: check again..replaced `orders_status_id ` with `orders_id`

Comment: @jonju i cannot able to get all data from my table it shows me error `Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Unable to save result set in /web/htdocs.... 1317 - Query execution was interrupted.  2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: This is connection problem..check your connection

Comment: it is connected..  i have 310k+ rows so i think it could not alle to get all data toghter ? do you have better idea ?